# Angular2 ngfor calling method 3times

Tags: angular, methods, ngfor

I try to call a method inside ngfor with

```
*ngFor=" let day of Days()" >{{day}}
```

The method:

```js
Days(){
 console.log("check");
 return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
}
```

It executes the template once, but the problem is that it logs in console 3 times "check".
Why it calls this function 3 times?

Template

```xml
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered year">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor=" let day of Days()" >{{day}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

controller

```js
export class MonthComponent{
    //public num: number;
    public lastday: number; 
    num = 1;
    Days(){
        console.log("check");
        return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    }

    getDays(){

        if( this.num == 1 ){
            let j=1;
            let d = new Date();
            let day = d.getDay();
            let today = d.getDate();
            let dif = today % 7;
            let days = [];
            if( day - dif <0){
                dif = day - dif + 8;
            }
            else dif = day-dif;
            for (let i = 0; i != 7; i+=1) {
                if(i < dif-1) days.push(31-dif+i+2);
                else {
                    days.push(j);
                    j+=1;
                }
                //console.log(days);

            }
            this.lastday = j-1;
            this.num +=1;
            console.log(days);

            return days;
        }
        else{
            let j = this.lastday;
            let days = []
            for (var i = 0; i < 7;i+=1) {
                j +=1;
                days.push(j)

            }
            this.lastday = j;
            console.log(days);
            console.log(this.num);

            this.num +=1;
            return days;
        }
    }
}
```

Days() is test function, indeed i need getDays()

Comment: can you add full controller and template code?

Comment: @SefaÜmitOray here you go

Comment: Because angular does automatic change detection. To know if the array returned by the method has changed since the previous time it checked the changes, it needs to call the method. That's completely expected and normal.

Comment: I get an error: "Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '3,4,5,6,7,8,9'. Current value: '10,11,12,13,14,15,16'." Can i somehow change this or i should change my logic? @JBNizet

Comment: Your method always returns the same hard-coded array. What is your real code? And more importantly, why don't you just execute this code once, in the ngOnInit method, to initilize a field of your component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid using functions/methods in bindings. Angular2 change detection executes them every time change detection is run.

Because for every call a different array instance is returned from `Days()` Angular2 change detection throws ""Expression has changed after it was checked." because this way change detection can't figure out when the model has settled because every time change detection checks it has changed (it doesn't check the content of the array, only the object identity)

To work around assign the result of the function to a property and use this property in bindings instead:

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.Days();
  }

  days:<number>[];

  Days(){
   console.log("check");
   this.days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
  }
}
```

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered year">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor=" let day of days" >{{day}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what if it''s a function with parameters? i mean, "let d of days(month)". it''s not a good idea to simply cache all results

Comment: You can cache the result with the parameter and when the parameter changes, then drop the cache and rebuild it. Calling methods or functions from binding that do actual work will hurt your applications prerformance badly. Just try to avoid that.

Comment: the possible parameters might be infinite. it can't be cached unless you clear the cache each time you know the loop ends. I think it should be a important feature of the NgFor directive.

Comment: I don't see how this changes anything. You can hold an (almost) infinite list of parameters and compare if one has changed. You can subscribe to parameter changes and just drop the cache when you get a notification. There are many ways to do it, but calling a method or function from the view should not be one of them ;-)

Comment: sure. drop the cache will do. my case is, there are many lists in the view. each one needs the function to get a different array. handling caches might be tricky. any way it still can be done. just needs more work. think it is much  better if features in ngFor